# How can i replace textbox with combobox at run time in .net window form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to replace my textbox with combobox at run time in my dot net windows form application
how can i do this

Comment: Have two controls and swap their visibility!

Comment: but i want my combobox exactly at the same location of my textbox

Comment: keep them at same location while designing... (I mean one on one). you are not trying to think here it seems..

Answer (score 1):

you shouldbe having boththe controls in page Div and based on ur requirement on some events you can swap the visiblity.

Comment: but i want my combobox exactly at the same location of my textbox

Comment: If you try see this you ll get in an HTML Visiblity tree it ll be in the same location when you hide any one. But again workout to be based on ur requirement

Comment: The OP indicated windows forms application.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all but I got the solution. I got the bounds of textbox and set those bounds to dynamically created combobox and then add the control to my form.